# Php foreach loop stops at PDO execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This page should add a record to a database at each loop.
However, when the loop reaches the $stmt->execute(), the loop stops.
I know the opendb.php I include should be right, I've used it before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <title> Afronden Bestelling </title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <?php include_once ('includes/navigation.php'); ?>
            <div id="main">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h1> Ik ben leeg :( </h1>

                <?php

                // Database name
                $dbname = "kledingwinkel";
                $factuurid = 1;
                $klantid = 42;
                $test = 20;

                // add record to database:
                include("opendb.php");
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO facturen ( productid, klantid, aantal, totaal, product_name ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');
                $stmt->bindValue(1, $test, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(2, $klantid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(3, $product_qty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(4, $subtotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(5, $product_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);


                foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
                {
                    //set variables to use in content below
                    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
                    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
                    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
                    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
                    $product_size = $cart_itm["product_size"];
                    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty

                    echo $product_name;
                    //echo $product_qty;
                    //echo $product_price;
                    //echo $product_code;
                    //echo $product_size;
                    //echo $subtotal;


                    $stmt->execute();
                }

                ?>

                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include_once ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is someone able to explain me what's going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting up the database connection? Also enable error reporting.

Comment: Are you sure you have the privileges to insert data into that table? But as PeeHaa said, some error reports would be gold.

Comment: perhaps you meant to use bindParam

Comment: Wrap the query execution in a try catch block so you can handle MySQL errors. The loop breaks because the query has an error. It can be anything from connection to field name to value format. MySQL tells you what is wrong so listen for it in your code and you will fix it very quickly

Comment: Also never share your db credientials in public sites even db name..

Comment: How do you understand that `when the loop reaches the $stmt->execute(), the loop stops`?